# sizeof member computation error

Tags: c++

I have such a structure (for some reason I cant just use an array):

```
  struct OperatorData 
  {
    char m_record_0[RIX_OPERATOR_CONFIG_SIZE];
    char m_record_1[RIX_OPERATOR_CONFIG_SIZE];
    //....
    char m_record_9[RIX_OPERATOR_CONFIG_SIZE];
  };
```

And I am trying to calculate amount of fields at compile-time:

```
enum {fieldsAmount = sizeof(OperatorData) / sizeof(OperatorData::m_record_0)};
```

And the compiler reports such a message:

```
Error:  #245: a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object
  enum{fieldsAmount = sizeof(OperatorData) / sizeof(OperatorData::m_record_0)};
                                                                  ^
```

I use keil uVision3 V3.60.
It doesn't matter where I place enum declaration inside or outside the structure. 
Why can't the compiler take size of this membmer?

Comment: The argument of `sizeof` should be a type (not true here) or an L-value (also not true).

Comment: @Matthias: The operand doesn't have to be an _lvalue_; any expression is allowed, as long as its type is appropriate for `sizeof`.

Comment: You should also consider the data alignment, controlled by pragmas, as described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/10207185/147763

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like your compiler doesn't support C++11 that allows the use of `Type::member` in unevaluated expressions. You'll have to manufacture an expression of the correct type, something like:

```
OperatorData* noImpl();

enum{fieldsAmount = sizeof(OperatorData) / sizeof(noImpl()->m_record_0)};
```

Comment: By the way, `OperatorData noImpl();` is also fine. Then you've to write `sizeof(noImpl().m_record_0)`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes. That is a function.

Answer (score 5):

Use typedefs:

```
typedef char RecordType[RIX_OPERATOR_CONFIG_SIZE];

struct OperatorData 
{
   RecordType m_record_0;
   RecordType m_record_1;
   //....
   RecordType m_record_9;
};
```

Then:

```
enum {fieldsAmount = sizeof(OperatorData) / sizeof(RecordType)};
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is safe; there can be padding added between or after the members, which will be included in `sizeof (OperatorData)` but not in any specific member's size.

Of course you could use the already-available `RIX_OPERATOR_CONFIG_SIZE` value to get an approximation:

```
const size_t num_records = sizeof (OperatorData) / RIX_OPERATOR_CONFIG_SIZE;
```

assuming it's only used for `char` arrays, and that it dwarves any padding.

You can also use `offsetof()`, this has the benefit of including at least padding between the members:

```
const size_t num_records = sizeof (OperatorData) /
       (offsetof(OperatorData, m_record_1) - offsetof(OperatorData, m_record_0));
```

Note, again, that this also is just an approximation. Hopefully, any padding will be much smaller than the members themselves so that their contribution will be rounded away.

Answer (score 3):

A non-static member cannot be accessed using `::` operator.

In C++11, you can do this ([quick demo](http://ideone.com/3U3Bv)):

```
#include <utility>

size = sizeof(OperatorData)/sizeof(std::declval<OperatorData>().m_record_0);
```

And in C++03, do this:

```
size = sizeof(OperatorData) / sizeof(((OperatorData*)(0))->m_record_0);
```

The type of the expression `((OperatorData*)(0))` is `OperatorData*`, so I use `((OperatorData*)(0))->m_record_0` to get the size which is roughly equivalent to this:

```
OperatorData*  od = ((OperatorData*)(0));
size_t size = sizeof(od->m_record_0);
```

But it is not exactly same, as the above statement will be executed, but the expression in `sizeof()` will not be executed.

Answer (score 2):

You first have to set the correct alignment using compiler pragmas ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1(v=vs.80).aspx in Visual Studio, http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html in gcc) otherwise `sizeof(OperatorData)` may be anything.

Then you have to have an instance of OperatorData from which you pick up the records and use them in sizeof()

Answer (score 0):

This is because `m_record_0` is not a static member of the struct `OperatorData`. You can only do that when it's a static member.

Comment: But isn't size of field known at the compile-time?

Comment: Yes, sizeof is a compile-time operator which is correct. The problem is you cannot refer to the member by OperatorData::m_record_0 no matter when, if m_record_0 is not a static member of your struct.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Object of your struct and use `sizeof()` operator on it.